# will be possible to be used

Tags: grammaticality, future, tough-movement

Is it (1) correct, (2) natural/wise to say the following in english: "[X] **will be possible to be used here as** [Y, ie. some function/role]"?

Are there any alternatives, and if there are, are they a superior or (else) a roughly equialent thing to say?

If it's not correct, could you point out what's wrong with it?

What I want to express is that in the future "you will be able to use X as Y here". *Ie. you will be able to use the ladder (not yet built) as an aid to climb up to the roof.* Of course I could use this form, but I'm trying to express it with the former to see if it is possible/OK. In particular I'm trying to avoid putting "you" or "one" in the sentence, but only if it's OK to do so.

Comment: *It will be possible to use X as function/role*.

Comment: Another alternative: *It will be possible for X to be used as function/role.*

Comment: @ЯegDwight, I see, thanks! I edited my question to ask what's wrong with my version. ps. You have a nice nick and one starting with that not-on-my-keyboard unicode key! :)

Comment: @PeterShor thanks! I guess my original version is incorrect, then?

Comment: Basically you are mixing up two different constructions, "it is possible to..." and "X is possible". I.e., I can't think of a situation in which "is possible" whose antedecent is the dummy it can be followed by an infinitive, unless you inject a "for X" the way Peter Short just demonstrated. X can't be the subject of both *be possible* and *be used* at the same time.

Comment: Yes. **Self-raising flour will be chosen / available to be used** is OK if verbose, because the flour is what will be chosen / available _and_ what will be used. But we are not thinking of _X_ as being possible, but rather just its _use_, in the original. A natural way to describe the situation naxa is envisioning would be:  **Making a ladder will make access to the roof possible.** Though this avoids the awkwardness with the tangled verbs by avoiding multiple verbs.

Answer (score 6):

In this statement, **[X]** is the subject of *will be possible*. But it's **not** [X] that will be possible.

What **will** be possible is *for X to be used here as Y*, the infinitive complement.

In other words, the sentence

- *For X to be used here as Y will be possible.*

is the original source. This can be [Extraposed](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299)

- *It will be possible for X to be used here as Y.*

But the subject [X] can't be Raised, because the predicate *possible* doesn't govern [Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), with either an active or a passive infinitive:

- **X is possible ... to be used here.*
- **X is possible ... to go here.*

and it also doesn't govern *Tough*-Movement, which would extract an object instead of a subject:

- **X is possible to use ... here*.

There **are** predicates that will work in these constructions:

- *X is likely to be used there.*
- *X is likely to go there.*
- *X is easy to use there.*

But *possible* is not one of them. Change the predicate and you change the constructions.

Answer (score 2):

*Possible* here relates to *use*, not to *[X]*.

> ***[X] will be possible to be used here as ...

(That asterisk in front of the sentence signifies it is *ungrammatical*).

However, I have seen some instances of such a sentence, and the reader probably assumes it to be correct and adopt it himself.

What may be a better though not elegant way to express your thought would be:

> [X] will be **amenable/suitable** to be used here as...

And, of course,

> **It** will be possible for [X] to be used here as ...