# "Making it easier to recognize A", "making A easier to recognize", and more

Tags: grammar

Are the following three sentences grammatically correct? If yes, what is the difference in the correct ones?

1. This will make it easier to recognize the object.
2. This will make the object easier to recognize.
3. This will make the object easier to be recognized.

Comment: (3) is ungrammatical; _easy_ governs _Tough_-Movement as in (2), and Extraposition, as in (1), but not Equi, as in (3).

Comment: @JohnLawler — Could you please translate your comment into a more standard English and  provide sources in support. I have no idea what 'Tough-Movement' means and even after finding it in Wikipedia cannot follow your argument. Likewise Extraposition. And has Equi got something to do with horses? Anyway, answers should be given as answers, not as comments. Why do so many people insist in ignoring the guidelines, although they are quite happy to mark down the answers of others?

Comment: I have no idea why people are so happy to mark down the answers of others; it puzzles me, too. But there are many things about the ELU format that are less than ideal. One of them is that people who ask questions about grammar are often unprepared to understand the answer, because it's too technical. FYI, [_Tough_-Movement](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/202701/15299), [Extraposition](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299), and [Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) are three syntactic rules in English.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*All* are grammatically correct. Which you use depends on desired emphasis and style.

In 1 the emphasis is on recognition, whereas in 2 and 3 it is on the object.

If you want to emphasize recognition I prefer 2 to 3 because the use of the passive in 3 makes the sentence more complex without adding anything.