# How to use the word difficulty correctly

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say: 
The city is difficult to turn into an economic center. 
OR it must be: 
It is difficult to turn the city into an economic center. 
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To infinitive used after adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277710/to-infinitive-used-after-adjective), which addresses tough-movement and includes 'difficult' as a tough-adjective. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_movement).

Comment: Both are correct. They are simply the result of different rules. The first is an example of [_Tough_-movement](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/202701/15299), and the second is an example of [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299). Both of these are syntactic rules employed to avoid saying the basic sentence, which is _To turn the city into an economic center is difficult_. This sentence has a heavy subject, and the main predicate is the last word; English does not like this kind of sentence and has rules to change them into more agreeable shapes.