# Please indicate to me which of the following is/are correct

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, active-voice

Which one is correct?

- The water level in the well is high enough to reach.
- The water level in the well is high enough to be reached.

I have searched on internet but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["a question impossible to answer" and "a situation possible to arise" Are they grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202679/a-question-impossible-to-answer-and-a-situation-possible-to-arise-are-they-g) Tough-movement validates the first variant. The second is a typical usage of 'adj + enough + to be Ved'.

Comment: They are both grammatical. How did you search this on the internet? What is the context?