# How difficult was that decision to make vs How difficult was it to make that decision?

Tags: word-order, tough-movement

> 1. How difficult was that decision to make?
> 2. How difficult was it to make that decision?
> 3. How difficult was that decision to be made?

Are there any differences among the above-mentioned sentences?

Comment: I agree with Ronald Sole's answer, but I'll add a subtle nuance some people may see.  #1 focuses on the decision.  It might elicit an answer comparing that decision to other decisions.  #2 focuses on the difficulty.  It might elicit an answer focusing more on the person's emotional or mental gymnastics in dealing with the decision.

Answer (score 2):

People are more likely to ask:

> How difficult was that decision?

without adding *to make*, although it's possible if slightly unusual, as in:

> How difficult was that house to build?

It's NOT correct to add *to be made*. Example 3 is wrong.

Example 2:

> How difficult was it to make that decision

is perfectly correct and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Well, these are questions that have been done things to, so let's unwind them first.
First, for convenience' sake, let's just say the answer to all the questions is *difficult*.
Then

- *How difficult was that decision to make?*
    is the question form of
  *That decision was difficult to make.*
- *How difficult was it to make that decision?*
    is the question form of
  *It was difficult to make that decision.*
    -- in which the rule of [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299) has transformed
          this sentence from something like
  *(For `P`) to make that decision was difficult (for `P`)*
          with all the agents deleted, a dummy *it* subject,
          and the infinitive at the end of the sentence.

Both of those are grammatical, and they mean the same thing, but they have different grammar.

The third question is a different matter altogether. It's ungrammatical.

- **How difficult was that decision to be made?*
    is the question form of
  **That decision was difficult to be made*, which is also ungrammatical.
       *Difficult* is a predicate that governs [*Tough*-Movement](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/82997/15299), which extracts a direct object.
       In this sentence Passive has applied, so *decision* is the **subject** of *to be made*, not its object.