# Position of relative clauses after verb

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english

I myself consider the sentence offset below to be correct; however, some of my associates regard it as being wrong. I would like your advice on it.
The sentence is

- *Jane Austen published 4 novels, who was an English novelist.*

While searching for some information that fits my needs, I came across this:
[image]

I wonder if this rule of grammar can fit in my sentence. Thank you.

Comment: *Jane Austen published 4 novels, who was an English novelist* reads at first as if the novels were the novelists. Quick fix: *Jane Austen, **who** published 4 novels, was an English novelist*.

Comment: No. << Jane Austen published 4 novels, who was an English novelist. >> might occur in some very old folksong or Gilbert and Sullivan, but sounds so outlandish to modern Anglophones that it would lose you a mark in an English essay and have people looking at you strangely if you came out with it in conversation. Note that the verb _arise_ in the example given has no object. I doubt that a relative clause is ever moved to the other side of _any_ {[V] + [DO]} string in natural prose or speech. Often, the DO will be a NP outcompeting for the relative clause.

Comment: -1 for including such a large tract of text *as an image file* - which means we can't cut&paste any of it for use in comments or answers. It's probably true, but I dont think it's relevant that "English prefers to have a verb as the second constituent of a sentence". What matters here is that native Anglophones don't like extended "parenthetical" text (such as *that smaller animals or plants do not have to cope with*, here) to come between the ***subject*** *(All kinds of problems)* and the ***verb*** *(arise)*

Comment: [Extraposition from NP](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105786/15299) doesn't work here, since the relative clause is non-restrictive. The original sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: In additionn to @jlawler's point, extraposition from NP usually occurs with intransitive verbs, not verbs that take direct objects.