# Grammar of "all's well that ends well"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, expressions, idioms

What is the grammar behind the phrase "[all's well that ends well](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%27s%20well%20that%20ends%20well)"? I understand what it means (all is well because it ended well) but could not for the life of me figure out how this meaning is derived from the original sentence. At first glance, it seems to have **two verbs**, which, as far as I can tell, is against all sorts of rules of English for a clause (all **is** well that **ends** well)? And what is the role of "that" in here? Is it to create a relative clause? Doesn't seem like it to me.

I'm dumbfounded by this phrase and I cannot understand its grammar at all. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please cite these "all sort of rules" that purport to forbid sentences from having multiple verbs. Have you confused clauses and sentences?

Comment: @tchrist I've rephrased the sentence, as I expected people to understand what I meant from context (I couldn't categorize it as a clause, let alone a sentence, since I don't know what its grammar is in the first place and is asking for help!).

Comment: I'd say it's a stylised / literary "inversion" from ***that (=anything)** [which] **ends well** [is] **all (=completely) well (=good)***. Compare ***Handsome is as handsome does***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does everything taste good that smells good? Do all projects end late that start late?  Does every traveller arrive early who departs early? Do all sentences sound “literary” that are phrased this way?

Comment: The key is, as John Lawler says, '**extraposition from noun phrase movement**.' In particular, with regard to your example, if you have a subject (here the word *all*) with a long phrase attached to the end of it (here the relative clause *that ends well*), and then a short verb phrase (here the verb phrase *is well*), the long phrase that would normally be attached to the subject, can skip over the verb phrase and appear at the end of the sentence. This is where we like to put long phrases in general. So we have an original sentence ...

Comment: ... "**All [that ends well]** is well", and after the relative clause gets 'extra posed' we get "**All** is well [**that ends well**]. So everything that ends good is good. Notice that *well* here is not the same adverb that we see in *he swims well* but the adjective *well* as in *Are you well?*. So literally more like *All that ends good is good*.

Comment: Well, I certainly think that as a general principle, this kind of "inversion" is a "literary" device. Did it exist before Shakespeare? I dunno. As it happens, I just watched Al Pacino's masterly delivery of ***All that glitters is not gold*** last night - another structurally similar "aphorism" that may have been coined by The Bard. Put it this way, these exotically structured utterances sound much more "literary" to me than more modern popular "sayings", such as *Life's a bitch and then you die, All coppers are bastards,* and *Well, he would say that that, wouldn't he?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think it's an inversion, really. (See JL's answer or my comment above). But I do love your list of popular sayings (which sound quite rhetorically excellent to me).

Comment: @Araucaria - Not here any more: In "literal, raw meaning" terms, I suggest that *All's well that ends well* is semantically indistinguishable from ***The end justifies the means***. It's just that the (socially well-established) *connotations* of the two utterances are poles apart!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try playing around with it and see what happens.

- *All's well that ends well*
- *All is well that ends well* (unwind the contraction)
- *All that ends well **is** well* (undo the [Extraposition from NP](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105786/15299);
  note that the *is* must be stressed here because it's the main verb)

All of these are grammatical and they all mean the same thing.
You can go on and unpack more; they'll fit, more or less, into the
last example above:

- *All* means *all events/things/jobs/parties/arguments/...*
- *Ends well* means (at least) *causes no injury or damage*, and may mean *is enjoyable*
- *Well* in *is well* means (the speaker claims) everyone is satisfied (they may be wrong)

Comment: Thank you, this cleared up a lot! I just have one more thing to ask though, which is that, why, does a sentence like (1a) "Something **that caused concern** came up", when extraposed into (1b) "Something came up **that caused concern**" sounds natural and grammatical, while the extraposition of (2a) "All **that ends well** is well" into (2b)"All is well **that ends well**" (seemingly) does not? Does (2b) sound natural to you, or is it of a literary style? If it does, could you please point out what the difference between 2a and 2b is that may have made (2b) so much harder for me to understand?

Comment: @lil'barbussy Not a native speaker, but both seems equally natural to me.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "the difference between 1b and 2b"

Comment: **VERDICT**: nevermind, i did some poking around on the internet and found [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/alls-well-that-ends-well.2827366/). apparently this is a very old saying from the 1600's when this kind of grammatical style was common, but **is obsolete now**. no wonder why i was so thrown off when i first read this. other examples of this: "All that glitters is not gold.", "All is lost that is given to a fool." thanks for introducing me to *extraposition* though, i greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. However, this particular rule is not called "Extraposition". That's a different rule, that moves heavy subject clauses and leaves a dummy _it_ to sound like a subject: _That this hurts so much bothers me_ extraposes to _It bothers me that this hurts so much_. **This** rule is called "Extraposition from NP" because it moves relative clauses from after the noun they modify, breaking up the NP (noun phrase) but not the subject, and leaving no dummy behind.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, there is no rule against having two verbs in a clause. For example: "I **may have been speaking**." You might have meant "finite verbs", which, when not coordinated, are generally limited to one per finite clause.

This sentence contains two finite verbs and two clauses. There is a superordinate clause ("all's well") that contains a relative clause ("that ends well"). A relative clause usually immediately follows its referent; in that case we would have:

> All that ends well is well.

In this case, the relative clause has been ["extraposed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) to the end of the sentence.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Oh haha, yeah. I deleted mine too; thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that you know the meanings of "well" in Shakespearean English.

> What is the **grammar** behind the phrase "all's well that ends well"?

**Main clause**:

"all - pronoun or anaphoric noun as subject

is - verb

well - adjective as predicative complement

**Subordinate clause**:

that - relative pronoun introducing a defining clause with the same referent <s>same</s> as "all"

ends - verb

well" - adjective as predicative complement

Comment: I am going to assume you know the meaning of relative clause (wink) and also that defining relative clauses with *that* generally modify the preceding noun phrase. But there is no preceding noun phrase here , only a seemingly fully formed clause- hence the OP's question. What is this relative clause modifying?

Comment: A relative clause may also modify a noun (or pronoun or noun phrase or anything acting as a noun). The referent of the modifying clause would seem to be "all." (Whether this is classified as a noun in this case or a pronoun is irrelevant)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. *What is this relative clause modifying?* -- **the same referent as "all"**