# with something to recommend it

Tags: meaning, grammar, ambiguity

I'm reading [an Economist report](https://www.economist.com/united-states/2023/02/16/should-tech-platforms-be-liable-for-the-content-they-carry) on mending an algorithm-related law called Section 230 and the last sentence (the part in bold, to be specific) confuses me a bit:

> When platforms “alert specific users” of videos or articles, Mr
> Wheeler says, “conduct becomes content” and should no longer receive
> Section 230 protection. Some advocates of curbed immunity distinguish
> between benign and destructive algorithms. “Somebody has to draw a
> line,” Mr Wheeler says. The question facing the justices is whether a
> line can be found **with something to recommend it**.

Does the sentence read like this:

The question facing the justices // is whether a line can be found // with something to recommend it.

If so, is "with something to recommend it" meant to modify "line"? And how may I interpret it?

Or there may be another explanation:

Is "something to recommend it" just another way to say "something like an algorithm"? Then the sentence reads like this:

The question...is whether a line can be found with an algorithm.

Which assumption is more probable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

*With something to recommend it* modifies *line* (a distinction between good and bad algorithms). They need to find a point of distinction that everyone agrees is the right one.

Comment: This is an example of the rule [Extraposition from NP](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105786/15299), which moves heavy relative clauses from the NP they modify, around short verb phrases to the end of the sentence.