# It's all I can do

Tags: idioms

> It's all I can do to stop myself from checking the website every 5 seconds!

I know what this phrase means, but does anybody know where it came from?  On the face of it, it doesn't make any sense.  This phrase stands on its own, and means "I find it difficult not to check the website every 5 seconds", so what, exactly, is all the speaker can do to stop himself from checking?  What does the "it" stand for?

Comment: I suggest you look [it](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/it) up in a dictionary.

Comment: "It" is *all you can do to stop yourself from checking the website every 5 seconds*, I guess.

Comment: *all* is *what* you can do to stop yourself from checking the website every 5 seconds, and nothing more, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

"It" in such sentences seems to take the place of an unexpressed subject.

E.g. "It's raining."

"It" in this case appears to take the place of "The weather at the moment".

Comment: So, in this case, the "it" would be whatever action the person is performing that stops thems from checking the website?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is.

Comment: Cyber, can such "it" be a false it? I.e., an "it" that has a grammatical function but no specific lexical meaning? Or, am I semantically wronglying?

Comment: The term is _[Extraposition](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299), and the _it_ is a dummy._

Comment: Thanks for that, @JohnLawler.  "Dummy" is so pejorative, though.  Wouldn't "placeholder" be more polite? :-)

Comment: _Dummy_ is the established term; politeness is about saving face, and words don't have any. This is a grammatical term, like [Pied-Piping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping) or [Sluicing](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Sluicing.pdf).

Comment: Yes, I was joking around.

Answer (score 2):

Example of the phrase being used without an antecedent:
[It's all she can do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neQ2FkmMspY)

At 2:43 CNN Reporter Chris Lawrence says, "In fact, she told me that sometimes it's all she can do to bottle it up and walk away."

There is no antecedent for it in this clip.  In this case, "it's all she can do to..." means "her only option is to".

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this phrase used where an "it" was not specified. Usually the sentence you provided would be preceded by something like "I've got to keep my mind occupied. It's all I can do to stop myself from checking the website every 5 seconds!"

Comment: So, "it" is "to keep my mind occupied" and "all" is "to keep my mind occupied", hence "it"="all", no?

Comment: That phrase is commonly used without an antecedent. Heck, looks for the lyrics to The Cars' "It's All I Can Do". The phrase starts the chorus and has no obvious antecedent in the verse.

Comment: @Ladlestein Yeah, that's because the lyricist is leaving the "it" open for interpretation. The listener assigns an appropriate value to "it" based on the context of the song. In OP's example there is no other context, which is why it is strange.