# In the sentence 'She seems nice', is 'nice' a subject complement, verb complement, or both?

Tags: complements

In the sentence below, is *nice* a subject complement, verb complement, or both?

> She seems nice.

According to [this page](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/enc2010/articles/verb-complements.htm), it’s a type of verb complement; but it also seems to me to fit with the description of a subject complement, as explained on [this page](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/objects.htm#direct_object).

Answer (score 1):

The most traditional terminology is that verbs like *seem* are [**linking verbs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb) that link the subject (or object) with their corresponding subject/object complements. A subject/object complement is also known as a **predicative**.

Predicatives are also complements to the linking verb, though: they are part of the predicate in the sentence. (With the verb *be*, in fact, they *are* the predicate, and the verb itself is just an empty placeholder that has to be there for the sentence to be grammatical.)

So the simple answer to your question is ***both***. A subject complement or subject predicative is automatically a complement to the main verb in the clause, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence below, there are all kinds of names for what *nice* is.

- *She seems nice.*

But the sentence above has been done things to.  An equivalent sentence is

- *She seems **to be** nice.*

from which the first sentence is derived by *To-be*-Deletion.

In other words, there is an infinitive complement here.
And *(be) nice* is its **predicate adjective**.
What you want to call *nice* after *to be* is deleted is up to you.

I won't go into [A-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) here, but *seem* is a prototypic A-Raising verb,
since what actually **seems** in this sentence is in fact  not *her*, and not *nice*, but rather
***that she is nice***.

*That she is nice* is also a possible complement clause with *seem*, although it requires [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299).

- *It seems that/like she is nice.*

And it means the same as the other sentences.

Comment: I keep finding references saying verbs like **be, become, seem** are *copulas* (apparently the same thing as *linking verbs*). Does that imply any special significance to the fact that one "expanded" version of OP's example actually contains *two* such verbs?

Comment: Yeah, that's what they used to be called, because it looked like they behaved the same way as _be_. But it turns out that _be_ is an auxiliary but _seem_ is a real verb that takes real complements. You realize there was no systematic study of English syntax before about 1950; it was largely ignored, or treated only in simple SVO sentences.