# Part of speech of "likely"

Tags: parts-of-speech, predicative-complements, predicate-adjectives

`It is likely to rain.`

Here *likely* is a predicate adjective with *to rain* as the complement (correct me if I'm wrong).

`Who took the cookie? It was likely Bob.`

Is *likely* also a predicate adjective here, or is it an adverb modifying *was*? It certainly seems like the case if one were to substitute *probably* in its stead, but I'm not certain.

Comment: It's an adverb. Also it's an adverb in _Likely it was Bob._ Adverbs can go in many different places. Of course, it means the same thing in either case, so there is no benefit to knowing that one usage is adjectival and the other is adverbial.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for the prompt answer. In `It is likely to rain.` why is it wrong to argue that _likely_ is an adverb modifying _is_?

Comment: Because _likely_ is the predicate adjective in that sentence. And nothing ever modifies _is_; it's always an auxiliary verb, and adverbs modify main verbs or verb phrases or clauses.

Comment: @JohnLawler Your second statement applies to `It is likely to rain` and not `It is likely Bob`, right?

Comment: Right. _It is likely to rain_ is [A-Raising](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/174782/15299) of _For it to rain is likely_, and _likely_ has the same role in both sentences.

Comment: @JohnLawler https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/533931/be-rid-of-get-rid-of