# be rid of / get rid of

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, past-participles, syntactic-analysis

`Finally, I got rid of Karen. / Finally, I was rid of Karen.`

1. *rid of* is a **phrasal verb** whose direct object is *Karen*
2. *got* and *was* function as **copular verbs**
3. *rid of Karen* together is a participle clause (past participle clause?!) which is adjectival and serves as the **predicate adjective** complementing *got/was*

---

Is my three-point analysis above right?

Comment: Except for the terminology, yes.

Comment: Phrasal verbs can be split by the DO, as in *tune up*. I *tuned* the car *up*.  Prepositional verbs don't do that. https://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/various-grammar-rules/phrasal-verbs-structure-and-examples#:~:text=Summary,comes%20directly%20after%20the%20preposition.

Answer (score 1):

*Be/Get rid of* is not a phrasal verb. *Rid* is an idiomatic predicate (the past participle of the verb *rid, rid, rid*) that combines with an auxiliary *be* like other participle adjectives like *tired* or *pleased*, and indicates an object by way of a preposition.

- *He finally got rid **of** that cold.*
- *He's pretty tired **of** hamburgers by now.*
- *He's quite pleased **with** the new dishwasher.*

In the case of *pleased* the preposition is *with*; in the case of *rid* and *tired*, it's *of*.

That works for both stative *be rid of* and causative/inchoative *get rid of*. They both use *of* because they both use *rid*. The difference between *be* and *get* is the difference between a state and making the state come about. That's what "causative/inchoative" means.

Comment: I'm curious if they are still considered prepositional verbs, or is there a test which *rid*, *tired*, and *pleased* flunk. Or should this be asked as a new question?

Comment: What's a "prepositional verb"?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your analysis.

It is possible for **rid** to be a pure adjective = clear/cleared of something that is unwanted.[1] It is now very rare as a true adjective. If it is accepted that “rid” is an adjective, then “of Karen” is an adverbial prepositional phrase modifying “rid” and “rid of Karen” is a complement, and there is no phrasal verb.

The alternative is that, as you say, “rid” is a participle modifier acting (with “of Karen”) as a predicate complement.

The OED also suggests that both to be rid of, and to get rid of are phrasal verbs with slightly different meanings:

> P1 a. to be rid of: to be freed or relieved from (a troublesome or unwanted thing or person).

> 2000   M. Barrowcliffe Girlfriend 44 iii. 91   I consider everyone as a life partner—apart from Gerrard, of course. One day I will be rid of him.

> P2. to get rid of: to remove or dispose of (a troublesome or unwanted thing or person).

> 2002   Woodworker Aug. 91/2   Smooth any rough edges to get rid of splinters.

I would disagree a little with this as **to be** indicates a state, whereas **to get/ become** indicates a **change** of state – as you say, both are copular.

[1] OED: Rid (adj.) rare. That has been ridded or cleared. Also rid-up.
1628   in H. Paton Dundonald Parish Rec. (1936) 246   He saw Robert Bowman fall on the rid land.

1866   C. Kingsley Hereward the Wake II. viii. 137   ‘We will make room for you! We will make a rid road from here to Winchester!’ shouted the Meeting, with one voice.

(You will see that **rid** expresses the idea of something that has been emptied of unwanted things.)

Comment: “slightly different meanings” may be understating it. “I got rid of Karen” could mean you killed her; “I was rid of Karen” could mean someone else killed her. Or just drove her out of the house. Does the OP think they’re equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

*Get rid of* and *be rid of* mean two different things.

In this instance **get rid of** means:
([MW.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20rid%20of))

> to *do* something so as to no longer have or be affected or bothered
> by (something or someone that is unwanted)

*Get* in this phrase is non-copular. "I got sick" has copular *get.* This is not like that. Instead, it's an action. *get rid of* is the phrasal verb.

**to be rid of** means:
([MW.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20rid%20of))

> to no longer have or be affected or bothered by (someone or something
> that is unwanted or annoying)

In this case, *be* is the copula and *rid* is an adjective:
[(Wiktionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rid)

> Released from an obligation, problem, etc. (usually followed by of)