# What's the underlying grammatical structure of this sentence with three instances of "it" and two of "being"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, dummy-it, absolute-constructions, anaphora

I just encountered the following sentence in *The Oxford Guide to Style* (p. 161) and could not figure out its structure:

> Since it⁽¹⁾ is being presented as a direct quotation it⁽²⁾ is treated as one, **it⁽³⁾ being immaterial that the words are not in English.**

Why can the the final instance of the pronoun *it*, the one labelled with a superscripted ‘(3)’, be inserted at the end?

The first two instances of *it*, those labelled (1) and (2), are clearly [coreferential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreference) to the same earlier antecedent (whatever is being presented as a direct quotation), but what is the third instance of *it* referring to?

What is the grammatical structure of this sentence?

Can that third *it* be omitted and the sentence remain grammatical and unchanged in meaning?

Comment: I can tell you this: it ain't the greatest English I have seen. And, for your information, one typically sees this usage in contracts, court cases and technical texts. A comma is missing direct quotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parenthetical participle clause

> - *it being immaterial that the words are not in English*

is the result of  [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/186643/15299) (with dummy *it* inserted) on the parenthetical participle clause

- *that the words are not in English being immaterial*

[Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/419328/15299) is very common in English when the subject of a short verb phrase (like *being immaterial*) is long and syntactically complex (like *that the words are not in English*). It moves the heavy material to the end, where it's easier to parse in a right-branching language like English, and leaves a harmless little one syllable marker that leads right into the auxiliary verb, which is what English prefers.

If you exaggerate these dimensions, you see how useful it is. Contrast

- *That I had to stand in line for over an hour yesterday is too bad.*

versus the extraposed version

- *It's too bad that I had to stand in line for over an hour yesterday.*

Oh, and as for the two *being*s, the first is simply the progressive construction operating on the passive *be presented*, producing *is being presented*, a tensed main verb chain. The second one is a non-finite equivalent of a tensed subordinate clause. In this case, something like

- *since it is immaterial that the words are not in English*

with the same extraposed clause. Unlike the first, this *being* is not tensed, since it's a participle.

Comment: Why necessarily parenthetical? As it means: and it is immaterial that the words are not in English. Seems to me to be a main idea here.

Comment: It's a subordinate clause, not a main clause. It's parenthetical because it's nonrestrictive. Whether it's a main idea or not has nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: It is subordinate, sure but I don't think it is "explanatory or qualifying". I  think it is necessary to the sentence. I said main idea, not main clause. I think I know the difference...

Comment: The clause is not necessary, since the decision is made. The subordinate clause is just a reason for making that decision.

Comment: For me, it means this: Since it⁽¹⁾ is being presented as a direct quotation, it⁽²⁾ is treated as one and it is immaterial that the words are not in English. So call it what you will. Meaning-wise there are two ideas, as I see it.

Comment: There are three clauses, two of which are subordinate to the main clause. Ideas are harder to count.

Comment: Of course: Since it is being presented as a direct quotation=subordinate=one||it is treated as one =main= two|| and it being etc. = three. You are calling three parenthetical which I would not.  If you remove it the meaning of the sentence is changed.

Comment: If you remove **anything** from a sentence, the meaning of the sentence is changed. All written sentences are multiply ambiguous to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Your highlighted text is what is called a nominative absolute, which is used to describe the subject of the main clause, the "direct quotation," but is essentially a separate clause in its own right, and has almost no bearing on the first clause - in other words, it is *completely* parenthetical. If reworded, it could stand as a separate sentence, as "It is immaterial that the words *[of the direct quotation]* are not in English."

The "it" you're questioning is the subject of this absolute, so no, it cannot be deleted and maintain the integrity of the sentence.