# Unusual model of clause

Tags: clauses

How this sentence "The weather being very bad, we did not start the journey" is reduced?
I cannot understand what structure is applied for the clause "the weather being very bad".

Comment: It is old fashioned. Today, we would say: As the weather was very bad, we did not start the journey.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a present participle follow a subject?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153848/can-a-present-participle-follow-a-subject) It's an **absolute clause**. From Wikipedia: 'In linguistics, an absolute construction is a grammatical construction standing apart from a normal or usual syntactical relation with other words or sentence elements. 

Example Usages:

“This being the case, let us go” / 

"The referee having finally arrived, the game began".... '

Comment: It's helpful.Thanks for your information

Comment: The clause "The weather being very bad" is a a supplement, more specifically an absolute construction. It qualifies as an absolute by being non-finite with a subject and subordinate in form but with no syntactic link to the main clause.

Comment: See also [What's the underlying grammatical structure of this sentence with three instances of “it” and two of “being”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522372/whats-the-underlying-grammatical-structure-of-this-sentence-with-three-instance)

Answer (score 0):

This part of the sentence is a non finite clause; the reason for this name is that the verb form is one of the non finite form, (in other words, a form that is not conjugated) (CoGEL, p. 993 § **14.6**). Only the relevant clause structure is considered below.

> (CoGEL **14.6**) The nonfinite clause may be with or without a subject. The classes of nonfinite verb phrase  serve to distinguish four structural classes of nonfinite
> verb clauses:
> (i) TO-INFINITIVE […]
> (ii) BARE INFINITIVE […]
> (iii) -ING PARTICIPLE […]
> ♦ without subject: Leaving the room, he tripped over the mat.
> ♦ with subject: Her aunt having left the room, I asked Ann for some
> personal help.
> When the subject of -ing clauses is expressed, it is often introduced by a
> preposition:
> ♦ With the audience turning restive, the chairman curtailed his long
> introduction.
> (iv) -ED PARTICIPLE […]

- The weather being very bad, we did not start the journey.

From the above, it follows that this is an ing participle clause with a subject (weather).

The function of the clause is adverbial of contingency expressing the reason.

- Because the weather was very bad, we did not start the journey.

This appears to be fairly clear from the following.

[Nonfinite Clauses. An analysis of to-infinitives and -ing participles in newspaper articles from “The Guardian”](https://www.grin.com/document/323736)

> 2.2.5 Adverbial
>
> All types of nonfinite clauses can be used as adverbials.
> […]
> -ing participle clauses are of two types […]. Those of the first type have an explicit subject; those of the second do not. The understood subject is identical to the subject of the main clause. They may be introduced by a subordinator. (Aarts 1988:167)
>
> -ing participle: “The referee being ill, the match had to be postponed.” (Aarts 1988:167)