# "It would be a better idea to" VS "A better idea would be to"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm contemplating these two sentences:

> I think it would be a better idea to show you my works.
>
> I think a better idea would be to show you my works.

as answers to a question "Can you tell me something about your art?"

1. How are they different?
2. Where is the emphasis in each of the two sentences?

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, but it seems that your first version might be pragmatically preferable.

Comment: *I think you would get a better idea if I showed you my works.*

Comment: Jim is the pragmatist. Both your suggestions are dismissive. 'It's probably best if I / Why don't I show you some of my works' doesn't convey the 'Not the best of ideas' connotation.

Comment: I think i formulated my question badly. I think what I mean is "do both sentences mean roughly the same, or is there a difference between them ,that make one of their parts more emphasised/stressed ?"

Like in:

Comment: Note: Usually an artist would say "showed you my **work**", uncountable.

Comment: To my ear, the first seems ever so slightly more like it implies the person asking the question has had a bad idea.  Very slightly, though.

Comment: Thank you for your imput.
Let me rephrase my question.  "Do both sentences mean roughly the same or each of them is slightly different?  And if they are different, then how?"

Like in:

"I think it would be a smarter move to tak to these guys"
or
"I think a smarter move would be to talk to these guys"

Is there any meaningful difference in each of these sentences or is it just a matter of word stress, that would make a particular part of the sentence sound more important?
P.S. Sorry for confusion, my English is too poor to talk about abstract grammar issues. Thanks for all your input though.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK What if they're etchings?

Comment: @IGO Yes, one of the differences between the two versions is the location of the NP "a better idea"; in one version, it is at the beginning of a content clause. Give this thread some time (a day or so?), and someone (or two) might come around later to write a decent answer post. :)

Comment: A "better idea"  than what? I think we need to know this.

Comment: @Margana Doesn't it mean *showing you my work would be better than telling you about it*?

Comment: _Doesn't it mean showing you my work would be better than telling you about it?_ Oh, yes it does. I missed that. Thanks Araucaria; sorry, IGO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a purely native speaker's (non-linguist) perspective: there is essentially no difference in the 'meaning' of these sentences. Basically they both say

> It is better to show you my work(s).

*Would* in English is a [*softening* word](http://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2014/04/30/would-you-mind-reading-this-please/), that is, a word or phrase which makes us sound less demanding.

For comparison,

- Turn down that music.
- Would you turn down the music, (please)?

In the same way,

> I think it would be a better idea...

is softer, less assertive than

> I think a better idea would be

Because you are asserting your preference over the person who asked you about your art, the *would* softens the response a bit.

Semantically, I'm not sure of the difference. *Would* indicates the consequence of an imagined event or situation. In the first, You're imagining that your idea is better (softer). In the second, you're pretty sure your idea is better, and are imagining that showing your work is better than speaking about it.

I think.

Comment: Don't both sentences have *would* in them, though old bean?

Comment: @Araucaria - Trust me, I'm not at all certain of this explanation. That's why we are fortunate to have people like you here!

Comment: I'm with @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I don't see either as being softer than the other

Comment: People disagree all the time. I gave my answer. Buty te person you should be agreeing with is Dr. Lawler, a professional (and excellent) linguist, so there! Read his answer, and then you'll you know.

Answer (score 1):

The Original Sentences are:

> *It would be a better idea to show you my works.*
>
> *A better idea would be to show you my works.*

(The initial *I think* adds nothing but syntactic complexity to either sentence, so let's ignore it, OK?)

The Original Questions are:

> 1. How are they different?
> 2. Where is the emphasis in each of the two sentences?

(1) is easy. The two OS differ in that the first one has undergone a variety of [the Extraposition transformation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299). That takes a sentence and rips it into pieces before reassembling it with a dummy pronoun subject, and the original subject on the other side of the verb phrase.

- ***To chop broccoli** is his fondest dream.*
- ***It** is his fondest dream **to chop broccoli**.*
- ***That he's smiling like that** makes me nervous.*
- ***It** makes me nervous **that he's smiling like that**.*

It's very common, especially with *that*-clauses and infinitive clauses as subjects.

(2) is not easy, at least as it's phrased, because it's not clear what is meant by *emphasis*, and what it might mean for this *emphasis* to be located at some point in the sentence. *Emphasis* has a number of meanings in English, but one of them has to do with syllable stress (*The emphasis is on the second syllable in "bedraggled".*)

However, if *emphasis* has anything to do with meaning, it's not anything that can be answered by syntax, because there's no meaning difference between two sentences related by a transformation. That's what "syntactic transformation" **means**.

Comment: It's so nice to see that you're still involved in the community. Nice answer, too, as always.